# Running fstrim as cronjob - what happens when interrupted by shutdown

Tags: ssd, trim

One of the ways to implement fstrim on a file system, it to make a cron.daily task that runs `fstrim /`. This is preferred over `-o discard` (mount option) by a lot of people, because the latter can make writing slower, especially deleting large amounts of small files.

My question then is, when I do make a cron job like that, what happens if this gets interrupted by a reboot/halt, or worse, a power loss? SSD's don't like power losses to begin with (there is even a SMART parameter to count them), and I can imagine that power loss during fstrim is even worse.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I still wonder about this.

Comment: For my laptop, I 'solved' it by putting `/sbin/fstrim /` in `/etc/rc.local`, so that it runs on boot. I can be pretty sure it won't get interrupted then.